# How to typeset radio buttons and rounded rectangles?

Tags: pdftex

I need to create PDF containing form as in screenshot. How could i create radio buttons and the rounded rectangles covering some text?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With tcolorbox package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{Form}
    \tcbox[colframe=white,arc=5mm]{\ChoiceMenu[radio]{Option 1}{ }}
  \end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My sincere compliments for your support and answer. Probably with a small shadow near radio button would be aesthetically better and very similar to the image.

Comment: @Sebastiano the button is done by viewer, not by latex. use other viewer